# Would a question about a specific English language tool be on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, resources, online-resources

Can language tools (typically, but not exclusively, software tools) be asked about on English SE?

I have a question about how I can work out *where* a term is used. It's along the lines of:

> A common use case is to see if a term or phrase is used just in one's own area (whether that be defined as their city, state, country, other), or if it's recognised in other parts of the world too.
>
> Some interesting words to look up could be
>
> - "my bad" - common expression in Australia to say "oops, my fault"
> - "nonce" - means a "unique number" in American computer terminology, but it's a rude term in Britain.
> - "jumper" - a garment warn for warmth on one's upper body in some parts of the world, but not a term used often (at all?) in the US.
>
> These are random examples for demonstration purposes.
>
> Is there any tool that can provide this geographic breakdown of *where* a word/phrase is used?

Comment: The tool you’re seeking is just a good old dictionary; they identify if a word is or has regional variations. Though they won’t likely cover modern slang (“my bad”), it takes a while for words to be established sufficiently to be recorded. There are some specialized dictionaries, such as the Dictionary of American Regional English (DARE), that analyze certain topics in greater depth than a general purpose dictionary. But I suspect you’d find both *nonce* and *jumper* in a standard dictionary (with *jumper* likely carrying an indication such as “chiefly Br.”).

Comment: In my dialect of American English, _jumper_ is a piece of female clothing. It does not mean _sweater_.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a reference or resource request. We don't allow them on the main site, but we do answer them here (i.e. english.meta). Just tag your quesiton [resources](/questions/tagged/resources)